# Как сократить время разбора Json`массива с сервера?

Tags: android, массивы, json, android-asynctask

Есть `AsyncTask`. В нем загружаем с сервера данные в `Json`-формате.

```
@Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {
            try {

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
                URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
                conection.connect();

                Reader reader;
                reader = new InputStreamReader(conection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader); 

                String line;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                }
                long sbtoStringlength = sb.toString().length();

                JSONArray jsonArrayAllItems = new JSONArray(sb.toString());

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArrayAllItems.length(); i++) {
                    JSONArray dataJsonItem = jsonArrayAllItems.getJSONArray(i);

                    //здесь отправляем в БД элементы Json с сервера
                    dbExpImp.setJsonData(dataJsonItem);
                    publishProgress((int) ((i * 10000) / sbtoStringlength));

               }
                reader.close();
                return true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            }
        return false;
    }
```

На выходе получается вот такая картинка
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Загрузка данных с сервера намного быстрее чем разбор "посылки" с занесением в БД. Дело в том, что этот процесс отражается в всплывающем Dialog`е и занимает относительно приличное время, на мой взгляд.

Вопрос.
Возможно ли как-то сократить время разбора `Json` массива с сервера?

Comment: Может попробовать XML?

Comment: Сильно подозреваю, что в этом коде самая медленная строка:                              `dbExpImp.setJsonData(dataJsonItem);` Пройдитесь профайлером - он покажет.